# Gosper's Mathematics

Tags: reference-request

Sometimes I bump into more of the astonishing results of Gosper (some examples follow) and I gather that a lot of them come from hypergeometrics and special functions.

- Have there been any attempts to try and collect together these?
- What papers/books and such are there which study collections of results like this?

---

$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\begin{matrix} -\frac{n}{2(2n+1)} & \frac{1}{2n(2n+1)} & \frac{1}{n^4} \\\\ 0 & -\frac{n}{2(2n+1)} & \frac{5}{4n^2} \\\\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix} 0&0&\zeta(5)\\\\0&0&\zeta(3)\\\\0&0&1 \end{matrix}\right)$$

from [A third-order Apery-like recursion for $\zeta(5)$](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0206178)

$$W(x)=a+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left\{{\sum_{k=0}^n {S_1(n,k)\over \left[{\ln\left({x\over a}\right)-a}\right]^{k-1}(n-k+1)!}}\right\} \left[{1-{\ln\left({x\over a}\right)\over a}}\right]^n$$

from a page about [Lambert's W-Function](http://bbs.sachina.pku.edu.cn/stat/math_world/math/l/l059.htm)

$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{e}\left(\frac{1}{3n}+1\right)^{3n+1/2}=
\sqrt{\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{3})}{2 \pi}} \frac{3^{13/24}\exp\left(1+\frac{2\pi^2-3\psi_1\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}{12 \pi \sqrt{3}}\right)}{A^4}$$

from [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InfiniteProduct.html)

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^2}{n^2}\cos(\sqrt{n^2 \pi^2 - 9}) = - \frac{\pi^2}{21 e^3}$$

from [On some strange summation formulas](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1255987146)

Comment: This looks Ramanujan-esque to me...

Comment: Ramanujaniacal?

Comment: SIAM publications...sort of...discuss some.

Comment: Well... there's HAKMEM: http://home.pipeline.com/~hbaker1/hakmem/hakmem.html

Comment: Should the sign factor in the last sum be $(-1)^n$ ?

Comment: What is $A$ in the denominator of the formula for the second infinite product?

Comment: There are two typos in the last sum. It should be $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\cos(\sqrt{n^2\pi^2-9}) = -\frac{\pi^2}{12e^3}$. 

Comment: @JohnBentin According to that link to Mathworld, $A$ is the [Glaisher-Kinkelin constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Glaisher-KinkelinConstant.html)

Answer (score 7):

The book 'Concrete Mathematics' by Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik discusses some of the work of Gosper, in particular a lot of detail on the Gosper-Zeilberger algorithm.  (It's also a really great book generally.)

Answer (score 7):

The obvious answer to your question is to search for papers authored by Gosper, or papers with Gosper's name in the title, such as [Pages from the computer files of R. William Gosper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1993-119-03/S0002-9939-1993-1179588-8/S0002-9939-1993-1179588-8.pdf).  But surely this answer is so obvious that you already know it.

A good starting point for understanding modern *methods* for handling hypergeometric and other special function identities (as opposed to just a *list* of spectacular identities) is the famous book [A=B](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html).

Many such identities begin life by being discovered experimentally and then proved afterwards.  A good entry point into the experimental mathematics literature is [Bailey and Borwein's website](http://www.experimentalmath.info/).

Answer (score 7):

Some of Gosper's results are studied, and proved, in the article ["Pages from the Computer Files of R. William Gosper,"](http://tinyurl.com/384dxab) by Mourad E. H. Ismail, Yu Takeuchi and Ruiming Zhang (Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society, Volume 119, Number 3, November 1993). Gosper's work is also discussed in Wolfram Koepf's book *[Hypergeometric Summation: An Algorithmic Approach to Summation and Special Function Identities](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3528069503)*. See also Wikipedia's [list of hypergeometric identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hypergeometric_identities).